# The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: contract-development

My apologies for de last code, it had to many spelling and syntax erros. I was able to compile the contract, however when I introduced the "**address**", "**string**" in the setter, at the function **allowProperty** to set the owner, the transaction revert. with the falow note:
transact to propertyTrasnota001.allotproperty errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.Debug the transaction to get more information.

this is a property transfer contract, if there is some one that can help my with this issue with some specific information.

This is the code, it did compile with (pragma 0.4.26) and a few alerts show up.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
```

contract propertyTrasnota001 {
    address public DA; 
    uint256 public totalNoProperty; 
    function propertyTransfer(){ 
        DA=msg.sender; 
    }
    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender==DA);
        _;}

```
struct property {
    string name;
    bool isSold;
}
//mapping
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => property)) public propertiesOwner;
mapping(address => uint256)IndividualCountOfPropertyPerOwner;   //mapping of how many property this person hold.
//events
event PropertyAllouted(address indexed _verifiedOwner, uint256 indexed _totalNoOfPropertyCurrently, string _nameOfProperty, string _msg);
event PropertyTransfered(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, string _propertyName, string _msg);

function getPropertyCountOfAnyAddress(address _ownerAdress)constant returns (uint256){
    uint count=0;
    for(uint i=0;i<IndividualCountOfPropertyPerOwner[_ownerAdress];i++){
        if(propertiesOwner[_ownerAdress][i].isSold!=true)
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
function allotproperty(address _verifiedOwner, string _propertyName)onlyOwner
{
 propertiesOwner[_verifiedOwner][IndividualCountOfPropertyPerOwner[_verifiedOwner]++].name = _propertyName;
 totalNoProperty++;
 emit PropertyAllouted(_verifiedOwner, IndividualCountOfPropertyPerOwner[_verifiedOwner], _propertyName, 'Property Allouted successfuly');
}    
function isOwner(address _checkOwnerAddress, string _propertyName) constant returns (uint){
    uint i;
    bool flag;
    for(i=0;i<IndividualCountOfPropertyPerOwner[_checkOwnerAddress];i++)
    {
        if(propertiesOwner[_checkOwnerAddress][i].isSold==true){
            break;
        }
        flag = stringsEqual(propertiesOwner[_checkOwnerAddress][i].name, _propertyName);
        if(flag==true){
            break;
        }    
    }
    if(flag==true){
        return i;
    }
    else{
        return 99999999;
    }
}
function stringsEqual (string a1, string a2) constant returns (bool){
    return sha3(a1) == sha3(a2)?true:false;
}
function transferProperty(address _to, string _propertyName)
returns (bool, uint)
{
    uint256 checkOwner = isOwner(msg.sender, _propertyName);
    bool flag;
    if(checkOwner != 99999999 && propertiesOwner[msg.sender][checkOwner].isSold == false){
        propertiesOwner[msg.sender][checkOwner].isSold = true;
        propertiesOwner[msg.sender][checkOwner].name = 'sold';
        propertiesOwner[_to][IndividualCountOfPropertyPerOwner[_to]++].name = _propertyName;
        flag = true;
        PropertyTransfered(msg.sender, _to, _propertyName, 'Owner has been Changed.');
    }
    else{
        flag=false;
        PropertyTransfered(msg.sender, _to, _propertyName, 'Owner Does not own the Property.');}
        return (flag, checkOwner);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `contract` keyword should not be capitalized. There are several errors in your code though. Dumping your code having all things fixed is not for this community.

Comment: ok, Markus, yes I am leerning by my self. ok i will take a look, thanks again.